# In the series, The Big O, how did Negotiator Roger Smith come to control the titular Megadeus robot?

Tags: the-big-o

I don't think this was ever clearly explain just *how* he got it. This was not an anime adaptation of a manga to my knowledge, so no help there. Given that their entire reality was a simulation, and "The Event" caused most of the city-states populace to have no memories from 40 years prior, this could just be part of the mystery. I was curious if anyone knew anything deeper.

Comment: I don't think that was ever answered.  IIRC, the series was abruptly cut short when Cartoon Network didn't renew it.

Comment: I'm guessing he stole it from Shinji Ikari when he wasn't looking

Comment: Too much for me to go through, but tons of info and theories at https://kiserai.net/bigo/

Comment: @Valorum Dude, you is a _fool_ when you ready! :-D